# Writing code in terminal mode?

Tags: ubuntu

I have to write shell code in terminal mode on Ubuntu. I already have the code and it does what it's supposed to, but I don't know how to write it in terminal mode. I am not allowed to use text editors. Below is the code which does what it is suppose to do.

```
echo "Part 2 of program" 

while true
do
read FIRSTNUMBER
read SECONDNUMBER
if [ $FIRSTNUMBER -eq 99 ] || [ $SECONDNUMBER -eq 99 ]; then 
    echo "You have exited part 2 of the program"
break;
elif [ $SECONDNUMBER -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "The number must not be 0"

else 
    math=$((FIRSTNUMBER / SECONDNUMBER))
    echo "$FIRSTNUMBER DIVIDED BY $SECONDNUMBER = $math" 
fi 
done
```

Now I have to create a file and write the code all in terminal mode. Again, I cannot use a text editor. I know how to create a file in terminal mode. However, I do not know how i am supposed to write code on terminal mode without using a text editor. I am supposed to append this code onto a file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this homework? Because there are only like two reasons you would ever do this in real life, and both of them involve an apocalypse of some kind.

Comment: Yes, it's homework. I still don't get why he assigned this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a very artificial restriction, however, for such tasks you can use.

`cat > filename.txt`

Type or paste (`ctrl-shift-v`) it in, then press `ctrl-D` when you're finished. You can use `sed -i` to correct your typos (unless that's also considered a text editor).

Alternatively, you could host the text somewhere online and use `wget` or `curl` to download it.

It's either coming from the keyboard or the net, so those are your options.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Will this be considered appending the code into a file?Also, just wondering how will I edit the code if I need to in terminal mode?

Comment: `cat >> filename.txt` will append more code onto the end of an existing file if that's what you need. To edit without a text editor is as tricky as the name "editor" suggests. You can use `sed -i`, and regular expressions which are really outside the scope of this question. If you're just stuck on a terminal with no GUI, there are lots of good terminal-only text editors, and I think `nano` comes with a standard Ubuntu install.

Comment: Again thanks for your help. I also cannot use nano. The only thing I can do is append code onto a file. I asked my professor and he said you do something like this... 'echo "Part 2 of program">>program.sh' Does this make sense? Will I be use this method for my program?